# undefined reference to dlopen using djgpp

Tags: dos, dlopen, djgpp

When I tried to compiled sqlite3 uding djgpp, it gives error undefined reference to dlopen, undefined reference to dlclose, undefined reference to dlsym etc.
On Linux if we use -ldl the problem is olved. However there is no dl.a available in djgpp.
Then how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to disable all parts of sqlite that need the support for loading executable objects dynamically.  I am not that familiar with the sqlite, but looking at its source configuration options, I'd start with `SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION`.